# Width of rotated circular segment from frontal view

Tags: geometry

With all in mind we know about [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment). Is it possible to calculate "width" of the circular segment when rotated and still seen from frontal view? I know the chord (C), angle, height and radius and would like to calculate L as can be seen in image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1hmg.png). Notice the start (left side) of the frontal view width starts at the edge of the circular segment. Could not come up with an aproach that would allow me to calculate the length of the "width" (L) of the segment. Is it even possible to calculate?

What I have tried is to somehow fit two [triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFU1f.png) (dotted green and black). And that is when it ends before it starts. Because there is too many unknown. I have not come up with another feasible solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: I ll add it to the question, but I have ended really quickly.